# How do disable tap-to-click while typing?

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, synaptics

Running Kubuntu 12.4 on a Thinkpad 410S.

I'm hoping to disable the tap-to-click mechanisms while I am typing, similar to what I can do in windows.  So far I have only been able to figure out how to:

1. Disable tap-to-click completely (in the the KDE touchpad control)
2. Disable the entire touchpad (not just tapping, even moving) in touchpad management for n seconds after typing.

Looking for somewhere in between.  I want the tap-to-click action disabled for n seconds after typing, but want the touchpad to continue to move the mouse earlier.

Comment: Something like this exists in gnome-control-center, perhaps it is an option that hasn't to do with gconf, so you could try installing gnome-control-center, setting the Option (somewhere in Mouse and Touchpad options) and then removing gnome-control-center again.